# How can I disable the tweet sound when using Click to Tweet in Notification Center?

Tags: macos, twitter, notifications

I really like being able to send tweets on Twitter from Notification Center, but I can live without the sound that plays when you click Send. Is there a way to disable or customize the tweet sound?

Answer (score 1):

The "tweet sent" sound file is located at

```
/System/Library/SocialServices/Twitter.socialplugin/Contents/Resources/TwitterSent.caf
```

If you remove or change that file, then the sound should change accordingly.

Comment: or, if you don't want to do anything drastic, `chmod 000 /System/Library/SocialServices/Twitter.socialplugin/Contents/Resources/TwitterSent.caf`
which makes the file unreadable but doesn't alter its contents.

Comment: I like the way you think, except that you keep coming up with answers very similar to the ones I'm about to post :-)